# Is there any good desktop (workspace) manager for lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Is there any good graphical manager of the desktops (a.k.a. workspaces) on Lubuntu? something that makes it simple to

- switch between multiple desktops
- add and remove running programs to separate desktops (default is you have to drag the application to the edge to place it on other desktops)

Comment: Please provide your release (we currently don't know which DEsktop you are using)

Comment: I use keyboard shortcuts to switch desktops myself - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html